# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build bfe8bf5b-8368-4db6-a64e-8272d269ed76 status: FAILURE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

Hi I am trying to do a deploy, but I am always receiving this follow error:

gcloud app deploy --promote

```
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build bfe8bf5b-8368-4db6-a64e-8272d269ed76 status: FAILURE.
    Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError", "canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"19241AD3","errorMessage":"INFO     FTL version php-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for php\......
'''
'''
''
     \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/inflector/zipball/ec3a55242203ffa6a4b27c58176da97ff0a7ae.
Check the build log for errors: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/bfe8bf5b-8368-4db6-a64e-8272d269ed76?project=242083926926
```

I clicked in the log link and I could found the message:

```
Pulling image: gcr.io/gae-runtimes/php72_app_builder:php72_20200223_7_2_27_RC00
php72_20200223_7_2_27_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/php72_app_builder
74b953307ba8: Already exists
3950d715ce49: Already exists
3c2cba919283: Already exists
67e17702fae0: Already exists
c9c3f388cea0: Already exists
ca58486204f9: Already exists
7c50188704c4: Already exists
a3db2666eee6: Already exists
3a2f66066536: Already exists
4fed2e436246: Already exists
55e34f1ef5fb: Already exists
763d8f23f109: Pulling fs layer
e093f0e5764d: Pulling fs layer
a17ebc6065d7: Pulling fs layer
c54b6a8f056f: Pulling fs layer
bd7e4441afd6: Pulling fs layer
748982344c7e: Pulling fs layer
cc953cec17dc: Pulling fs layer
c59ab3553ad2: Pulling fs layer
f2c0883e8684: Pulling fs layer
5dff221051ac: Pulling fs layer
......
......
......
......

 - Installing torann/geoip (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

ERROR    error: `composer_install` returned code: 1
INFO     composer_install took 43 seconds
INFO     building_composer_json_layer took 43 seconds
INFO     build process for FTL image took 43 seconds
INFO     full build took 43 seconds
ERROR    `composer_install` had stderr output:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Package operations: 68 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
......
......
......
......
 - Installing prologuetech/big (v1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing torann/geoip (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

error: `composer_install` returned code: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 57, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 58, in UserErrorHandler
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
```

Could somebody save me? please!

Comment: Could you please share you requirements.txt file? Did you share the complete error? Could you also share the error logs for your App Engine instance in Logging?

Comment: Ok! I will do that, I just didn't want to put a gigantic log text here...

Comment: Just wanted to know if in the error it says something related with pip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, And I will answer my own question because maybe someone could be with the same problem...

I read this message:

```
"errorMessage":"INFO     FTL version php-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for php\
```

So I tried to do a **composer update**, and run **php artisan serve**, and in both cases the same error:

```
In Finder.php line 602:

  The "" directory does not exist.
```

So, I thought to take a look into my config folder, and to my surprise this folder disappears!

therefor, I needed to recreate the folder with all files and run again **composer install**.

After that, I could run again the **php artisan serve** and I could do the deploy:

gcloud app deploy --promote

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 5 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...done.
Setting traffic split for service [default]...done.
Deployed service [default] to [https://xxxxxx.appspot.com]

You can stream logs from the command line by running:
  $ gcloud app logs tail -s default

To view your application in the web browser run:
  $ gcloud app browse
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and this answer helped me to solve it. It was a mistake inside some file I edited. Found the issue using `composer update` and It displayed the issue more clearly in the console.